# Fixing out of sync sequence with PL/SQL

Tags: plsql, flyway

Someone inserted data here and there without using the sequence so now some tables are out of sync,
I made this script to repair them.

```
declare
    l_val number;
    maxvalueid number;
begin
    execute immediate 'select s_ref_declinaison_geo.nextval from dual' INTO l_val;
    execute immediate 'select max(id_technique) from t_ref_declinaison_geo' INTO maxvalueid;
    execute immediate 'alter sequence s_ref_declinaison_geo increment by +' || maxvalueid-l_val;
end;
/
```

however I get

```
PLS-00382: expression du mauvais type (bad type expresion)
ORA-06550: Ligne 7, colonne 5 :
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
Location   : sql/V12.x/xxxxx.sql (C:\checkouts\web\xxxxx-data\flyway\sql\V12.x\XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX)
Line       : 4
Statement  : declare
    l_val number;
    maxvalueid number;
begin
    execute immediate 'select s_ref_declinaison_geo.nextval from dual' INTO l_val;
    execute immediate 'select max(id_technique) from t_ref_declinaison_geo' INTO maxvalueid;
    execute immediate 'alter sequence s_ref_declinaison_geo increment by +' || maxvalueid-l_val;
end;


Une erreur est survenue lors de l'exécution de flyway.
```

so I'm guessing it does not like : `maxvalueid-l_val`

But why?

Thanks.

EDIT :

here is the final script

```
DECLARE
    l_val number;
    maxvalueid number;
    offset number;
BEGIN
    execute immediate 'select s_ref_declinaison_geo.nextval from dual' INTO l_val;
    execute immediate 'select max(id_technique) from t_ref_declinaison_geo' INTO maxvalueid;
    offset := maxvalueid-l_val;
    IF offset > 0
        execute immediate 'alter sequence s_ref_declinaison_geo increment by +' || offset;
        execute immediate 'select s_ref_declinaison_geo.nextval from dual' INTO l_val;
        execute immediate 'alter sequence s_ref_declinaison_geo increment by +1';
    END IF
END;
/
```

Comment: What was the previous "increment by"?

Comment: no previous increment by, someone inserted with hardcoded ids. curval is 6 in the sequence max id is 87564. I need to set the curval to 87564. I'm not doing it manually because I will make this script run on several tables

Comment: There is ALWAYS an increment by on a sequence. The default is 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it with a temporary var:

```
 declare
     l_val number;
     maxvalueid number;
   t number ;
   v varchar2(100);
 begin
     execute immediate 'select s_ref_declinaison_geo.nextval from dual' INTO l_val;
     execute immediate 'select max(id_technique) from t_ref_declinaison_geo' INTO maxvalueid;
   t := maxvalueid-l_val ;
   v := 'alter sequence s_ref_declinaison_geo increment by +' || t ;
     execute immediate v ;
 end;
 /
```

Answer (score 1):

From the comments I'm making an assumption:

I think you want to reset the sequence to start at a new number. According to [ALTER SEQUENCE](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_2014.htm#SQLRF00817) from the [Oracle Database Online Documentation Library, 12c Release 1 (12.1.0.2)](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/index.htm):

> To restart the sequence at a different number, you must drop and re-create it.

Using `START WITH` will give it a new starting point. Please note that this creates a default sequence. You should check all the settings of your current sequence before executing this:

```
declare
    maxvalueid number;
begin
    select max(id_technique) INTO maxvalueid from t_ref_declinaison_geo;
    execute immediate 'drop sequence s_ref_declinaison_geo';
    execute immediate 'create sequence s_ref_declinaison_geo start with ' || (maxvalueid + 1);
end;
```

---

This should make your procedure work (it doesn't understand the calculation, so `()` are needed). Your `SELECT` do not need any `execute immediate`:

```
declare
    l_val number;
    maxvalueid number;
begin
    select s_ref_declinaison_geo.nextval INTO l_val from dual;
    select max(id_technique) INTO maxvalueid from t_ref_declinaison_geo;
    execute immediate 'alter sequence s_ref_declinaison_geo increment by +' || (maxvalueid-l_val);
end;
```